# How can I issue a warning for only one instance of a module?

Tags: system-verilog

I am creating some System Verilog models of analog blocks in my chip. I am starting out with rough models and when I have time will review them with the analog designer to refine them. So I don't forget I have issued warnings inside the module:

```
initial $warning("Model has not been review with design");
```

This works a bit too well since some of these models are instanced thousands of times, resulting in a huge amount of noise in the log. How can I get this warning to be emitted only for the first instance? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
initial begin
   // Issue a warning only once for this module
   automatic bit warn_done = 1'b0;
   if(!warn_done) begin
      warn_done = 1'b1;
      $warning("Model not reviewed with design");
   end
end
```

It would be even better if this were a compile time warning, but I have the same question: How do I just get it issued once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a static variable in the compilation unit of your module.

```
int warn_done = 0;
module Model;
  initial if (!warn_done++) $warning("Model not reviewed with design");
  ...
endmodule
```

Comment: Will that variable be global to the whole design? That would mean I need a unique variable name for each module that does this. That’s ok, just not ideal.

Comment: It's global to the compilation unit. If you compile each module in a separate compilation command, each step creates a separate $unit. Some tools like Modelsim/Questa treat each file as a separate compilation unit by default.

Comment: Got it. Ok, I will experiment with my tools to see how it goes.